Get most recent of two different records for each group
I would like to find the most recent record for task A and task B for each ID by assign_date. The data is in the format



ID
task
assignee
assign_date




ID1
taskA
assignee1
date1


ID1
taskB
assignee2
date2


ID1
taskA
assignee3
date3


ID1
taskC
assignee4
date4


ID2
.....
.........
.....



and I'd like for the final result to be something like



ID
assignee_taskA
assignee_taskB



where the assignee is the most recent one by the assign_date.
I know there are a lot of solutions for most recent single record within a group but I'm hoping to do this with pivot/conditional aggregation so I don't have to do multiple joins.

I know there are a lot of solutions for most recent single record within a group , Well, you could try to show those methods which you already know.

Note that tables have rows, not records.

Can you add a few more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result - i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Just select the latest row and then do the pivot table.
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    task,
    assignee,
    assign_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, task ORDER BY assign_date DESC) AS r_n
  FROM source_table
),

latest_data AS (
  SELECT * FROM data
  WHERE r_n = 1
)

SELECT * FROM latest_data
PIVOT (MAX(assignee) FOR task IN ('taskA', 'taskB'))

